# diagnostics during hardware failure

Tags: ros, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to find out best practice for using ROS diagnostics in hardware drivers. For example, say I am writing a driver to communicate with a device over serial port. When device node is launched, assume that the serial port could not be opened. In such a case, should the device node keep running with diagnostics updates or should it end the process? I would choose diagnostics updates over abort. Any comments are appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12189/diagnostics-during-hardware-failure/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd assume that it's really different for every system. It will come down to how you want to handle it. I know that on our project, when a hardware device cannot be connected, we have set up a "watchdog" process that monitors the status of the hardware devices and restarts any device that's malfunctioning.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use a similar approach to @DimitriProsser, while gradually evolving my drivers to publish `driver_base` style states. When a device open fails, the driver publishes a `CLOSED` state, but continues to (slowly) poll the device in case it starts working. When successful, the state changes to `OPENED` or `RUNNING`, as appropriate. That allows other nodes to provide useful fall-back behavior in some situations.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2